# Circular reference in C++ without pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, circular-reference

Is there a way to define circular references without using pointers?

I need to have somthing like this:

```
struct A;
struct B {
    A a;
};

struct A {
    B b;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note: It seems fishy to me to forward-declare `A` to be a `class` and later define it as a `struct`.

Comment: The above cannot possibly compile - and doesn't under vs2008 - because A is not defined when struct B is being defined.  (btw, yes your forward declarations: struct/class should match the definitions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use references instead

```
struct A;
struct B {
  A& a;
};

struct A {
  B b;
};
```

But no it's not possible to create a circular reference without some level of indirection.  What your sample is doing is not even creating a circular reference, it's attempting to create a recursive definition.  The result would be a structure of infinite size and hence not legal.

Comment: How could this work? If I remember correctly, the address value of a reference can't be modified once set, so you can't define a circular reference.

Comment: @John, truthfully I'm not sure.  The OP though asked if it was possible to define one.  This definition is legal and compiles (VS2008 SP1).

Comment: The constructor for B would take a reference to an A, and the constructor for A would initialize its B member with *this.

Comment: You may do the following to use them: `struct { B b; A a; } c = { { a }, { b } };`

Comment: can this work?

struct A;
struct B {
  A* a;
};

struct A {
  B* b;
};

Answer (score 15):

No, there's not. Such structure would have infinite size.

You can use smart pointers ([shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) and [weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm)) to avoid direct pointer manipulation, but that's about it.

Answer (score 7):

> How could this work? If I remember correctly, the address value of a reference can't be modified once set, so you can't define a circular reference.

It could work like the following (same as Jared's example plus constructors defined):

```
struct A;

struct B {
  A& m_a;
  B(A& a) : m_a(a) {}
};

struct A {
  B m_b;
  //construct B m_b member using a reference to self
  A() : m_b(*this) {}
  //construct B m_b member using a reference to other
  A(A& other) : m_b(other) {}
};
```

Comment: Old thread, but i just used your solution in a state machine, see comment below.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `T o` means "an object of type `T`, not a reference to some `T` (as, for example, with reference types in C# and Java). With the code from your question, type `A` would have a sub object of type `B` (named `b`), and that `B` in turn would have a sub object of type `A` (named `a`). Now, that `a` would in turn have another `A` inside (again called `a`), which then has another `B`, which...

No, this will not work.

What you probably want is that an `A` *referres* to a `B`, which in turn referres that `A`. This can be done using pointers:

```
struct A;
struct B {
    A* a;
    B(A*);
};

struct A {
    B* b;
    A(B* b_) : b(b_)  { if(b) b.a = this; }
};

B::B(A* a_) : : a(a_) { if(a) a.b = this; }
```

I don't think it can be done using references.

Answer (score 0):

ChrisW's solution can be generalized a bit like this :

```
template <class defaultState> struct Context;

struct State1 {
    Context<State1>& mContext;
    State1(Context<State1> & ref) : mContext(ref) {}
};

template <class TDefaultState>
struct Context {
    TDefaultState mState;
    Context() : mState(*this) {}
};
```

This now allows you to do

```
Context<State1> demo;
```

Further, State can have some template helper code as well

```
template <class State>
struct TState {
    typedef Context<State> TContext;
    typedef TState<State> TBase;
    Context<State> & mContext;
    TState(Context<State> &ref) : mContext(ref) {}
};

struct State2 : TState<State2> {
    State2(TContext & ref) : TBase(ref) {}
};
struct State3 : TState<State3> {
    State3(TContext & ref) : TBase(ref) {}
};
```

Which now allows you to do any of

```
Context<State2> demo2;
Context<State3> demo3;
```