# Error "Unterminated conditional directive" in cross-referencing headers

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, include, header-files

There are two classes that are related to each other in their headers:

**PlotMarker**

```
#ifndef PLOTMARKER_H
#define PLOTMARKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include "plotter.h"

class Plotter;

class PlotMarker : public QObject
{
    // ...
    Plotter* m_attachedPlot;    
    // ...
};

#endif // PLOTMARKER_H
```

**Plotter**

```
#ifndef PLOTTER_H
#define PLOTTER_H

// ...
#include "plotmarker.h"
// ...

class PlotMarker;

class Plotter : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    // ...
    QLinkedList<PlotMarker*> m_markerList;
    // ...
};

#endif // PLOTTER_H
```

The program is compiled well, but it's got a error `error: unterminated conditional directive` in `#ifndef` and the code of classes in the IDE isn't highlighted because of it.

If I remove `#include "plotter.h"` in PlotMarker's header or `#include "plotmarker.h"` in Plotter's header, Qt Creator highlights the code as usual, but the compilating fails because of errors about invalid use of incomplete type.

Could you please tell me what's wrong? I think it's because of wrong headers cross-referencing, but I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429336/cross-referencing-included-headers-in-c-program) and it didn't help me.

Comment: I hit the same error on a Friday afternoon. I stupidly deleted the `#endif /* foobar_h */` out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I just moved one of `#include` from the header to the source file, and it has worked.

**plotmarker.h**

```
#ifndef PLOTMARKER_H
#define PLOTMARKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Plotter;

class PlotMarker : public QObject
{
    // ...
    Plotter* m_attachedPlot;    
    // ...
};

#endif // PLOTMARKER_H
```

// ...

**plotmarker.cpp**

```
#include "plotmarker.h"
#include "plotter.h"
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer guided me to reduce the includes. 
I used `namespaces` to solve the issue.

Comment: @Maubeh what do you mean you solve this with namespaces?

Comment: @MNCODE
Sorry for the late reply. The following link helped me resolve the issue. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental design flaw.
For example

```
#include "b.h"

class A
{
  B b;   // B is an object, can't be forward declared
};
```

a.h header file above

```
#include "a.h"

class B { 
         A* a // A is an object, can't be forward declared
};
```

b.h header file above

This is a Circular Dependencies

The compiler will do the following:

```
#include "a.h"

   // start compiling a.h
   #include "b.h"

      // start compiling b.h
      #include "a.h"

         // compilation of a.h skipped because it's guarded

      // resume compiling b.h
      class B { A* a };        // <--- ERROR, A is undeclared
```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of `#ifndef` and `#define` to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just gotten "`unterminated conditional directive`" in `#ifndef` and "`invalid preprocessing directive`" in `#end`.

I've just added "if" after `#end`(edit "`#end`" to "`#endif`"), that error is fixed.